# Exclude Javascript Function from iPad

Tags: jquery

I currently am using a script that executes a fade effect when mousing over icons (It fades them from color to black and white).  I'm having issues with it not working properly on an iPad or iPhone because of the hover event.

Is there any way to wrap the following in a conditional that will exclude an iPad, iPhone and possibly even a droid device from running it?

```
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $("ul.gallery li").hover(function() { //On hover...
            $(this).siblings().each(function () {
                var thumbOver = $(this).find("img").attr("src"); //Get image url and assign it to 'thumbOver'
                    //Set a background image(thumbOver) on the &lt;a&gt; tag
                $(this).find("a.thumb").css({'background' : 'url(' + thumbOver + ') no-repeat center bottom'});
                    //Fade the image to 0
                    $(this).find("span").stop(false,false).fadeTo('normal', 0 , function() {
                    $(this).hide() //Hide the image after fade
                        });
                });
            } ,
            function() { //on hover out...
                $(this).siblings().each(function () {
                        //Fade the image to 1
                    $(this).find("span").stop(false,false).fadeTo('normal', 1).show();
                    });
                    });
            });
    </script>
```

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check for 'iPad' using `navigator.platform`:

```
// Is the user on an iPad?
var isIpad = navigator.platform.toLowerCase() === "ipad";
```

similarly, you can check for other iDevices using an object literal and the `in` operator:

```
// Is the user on an iDevice?
var isIDevice = navigator.platform.toLowerCase() in {
    "ipod": true,
    "ipad": true,
    "iphone": true
};
```

to keep your code from running under these conditions, you can keep your setup logic above in a named function and execute it conditionally on DOM-ready, such as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() {

    // Setup routine
    var ready = function() {
        $("ul.gallery li").hover(function() { //On hover...
            $(this).siblings().each(function () {
                var thumbOver = $(this).find("img").attr("src"); //Get image url and assign it to 'thumbOver'
                //Set a background image(thumbOver) on the &lt;a&gt; tag
                $(this).find("a.thumb").css({'background' : 'url(' + thumbOver + ') no-repeat center bottom'});
                //Fade the image to 0
                $(this).find("span").stop(false,false).fadeTo('normal', 0 , function() {
                    $(this).hide() //Hide the image after fade
                });
            });
        },
        function() { //on hover out...
            $(this).siblings().each(function () {
                //Fade the image to 1
                $(this).find("span").stop(false,false).fadeTo('normal', 1).show();
            });
        });
    };

    // Current platform
    var platform = navigator.platform.toLowerCase();

    // List of iDevice platforms
    var iDevices = {
        "ipod": true,
        "ipad": true,
        "iphone": true
    };

    /*
    // OPTION 1:
    // On DOM-ready, execute for everthing except iPad
    $(function() {
        if ( platform !== "ipad" ) {
            ready();
        }
    });
    */

    // OPTION 2
    // Only execute if not an iDevice
    $(function() {
        if ( !(platform in iDevices) ) {
            ready();
            $(window).resize(function () {
                viewportSize();
            });
        }
    });

})();
```

to be honest, i've never done android detection, but there should be a similar method.

hope that helps! cheers.

Comment: Keegan,

Thanks for the great reply.  I'm a beginner when it comes to coding.  Could you demonstrate how to actually put in your device checker that you supplied actually into the code above?  I'm not sure exactly how to incorporate everything together.  Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelHarmon, i edited the example so that it is more complete, you can take the entire script above and replace the one from your example. i've added the check to only run the setup code if the user is not on an iPad. if you wanted to exclude iDevices completely, replace the code under `OPTION 1` with the code from `OPTION 2`.

Comment: Keegan, I copied it as is -- leaving off the information about Option 2 and the script is no longer functioning at all.

Comment: @MichaelHarmon it looks like there was a syntax issue in the original code that i missed, it has been replaced in my answer above. i also cached some selectors for you, to avoid finding the same elements repeatedly.

Comment: Keegan, Thank You.  One issue though -- the functionality that it was doing -- is now only half working.  If you go to:

http://209.142.68.153/

Click on "Work Showcase" in the menu -- when it scrolls over, highlight an icon and the others fade out.  The only thing though -- the one you have highlighted -- was supposed to stay in color.

Also -- I think I want to exclude iphones and ipods also -- would I just need to change the if (platform) call?

Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelHarmon sorry, i must've broken something when i was refactoring your setup logic. i added it back, exactly as it was in your question. as for excluding iphones and ipods as well, you'll want to use `OPTION 2`, which is now in place instead of `OPTION 1`

Comment: It works perfectly.  Thanks for going back and forth with me on this.

Comment: I have another quick question . . . I need to have the same thing done for this small piece of code (exclude if it is an iphone, ipod, or ipoad . . . ) could you format this also?

        jQuery(window).resize(function () {

           viewportSize();
        });

Comment: @MichaelHarmon i added that snippet inside the check, it should now run as expected (obviously though, you'll need to add the `viewportSize` function yourself).

Comment: Keegan, thanks so much.  I forgot to mention that this viewport script actually runs on a different page -- so would I just need to replace the top part of the script with the viewport script or is what you wrote for two scripts?

Comment: Keegan, using your code I was able to figure it out.  You saved me again. Thank You.